# Lambda Function Call

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

The following is a code snippet which I don't seem to get. The question is how to make the function output the desired result (not mentioning what the desired result is, I assume its printing 0 to 9).

Here is the question:
*What does the below code snippet print out? How can we fix the anonymous functions to behave as we'd expect?*

```
functions = []
for i in range(10):
    functions.append(lambda : i)

for f in functions:
    print(f())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, no new scope will be produced in `for loop`

So after `for i in range(10)`, the variable `i` is still exist, and its value == 9. And the lambda function `lambda : i` access the variable i

In order to output your desired result, you should pass the variable as a function argument in loop

```py
functions = []
for i in range(10):
    functions.append(lambda i=i: i)

for f in functions:
    print(f())
```